# Set strings values of a columns as a columns names

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have that in samples 1 the x,y and z values are respectively 100, 200 and 300.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 100 |
| 1 | y | 200 |
| 1 | z | 300 |

How can I transpose the table making as a column names the values x, y and z? Keeping ordered the values for each samples of column C?
I would like to achieve something like this:

| A | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 300 |

Thanks!

Comment: Check pivot_wider from package tidyr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# load package
library(data.table)

# set dataframe as data table
setDT(df)

# pivot long to wide
dcast(df
      , a ~ b
      , value.var = 'c'
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,1), B=c("x", "y", "z"), C=c(100,200,300))
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from="B", values_from="C")

# A tibble: 1 x 4
      A     x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   100   200   300
```